# Couchbase no error connecting to missing DB

Tags: go, couchbase

**Problem:** when i try to connect to a missing db the returned cluster is set and no error is returned.

```
cluster, errCon := gocb.Connect("couchbase://127.0.0.1")
```

**errCon** is nil and **cluster** is initialized

The first error occurs when i try to open a bucket. The error from opening the bucket is:

> "failed to connect to any of the specified hosts"

which one would expect when trying to connect. I have the latest sdk version from "github.com/couchbase/gocb"

Comment: What is the error you get when executing a query?

Comment: @AlexanderKohler it was opening a bucket. the error msg is "failed to connect to any of the specified hosts"

Comment: don't you need to specify the port?

Comment: @Alessio apparently not. i took the line from their official examples.

Comment: too bad, you can't create issue on their github